# Meteor Up error when deploying to Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up, node-fibers, fiber

Having trouble deploying a Meteor project to an Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel: Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic) instance on Digital Ocean using Meteor Up.

`mup setup` runs fine, so no problems in mup.json.

Then, when I run `mup deploy` I get:

```
Started TaskList: Deploy app 'stocksearch' (linux)
[x.x.x.x] - Uploading bundle
[x.x.x.x] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[x.x.x.x] - Setting up Environment Variables
[x.x.x.x] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[x.x.x.x] - Invoking deployment process
[x.x.x.x] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
de_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
s
bindings@1.0.0 node_modules/bindings

nodeunit@0.9.1 node_modules/nodeunit
└── tap@0.7.1 (inherits@2.0.1, buffer-equal@0.0.1, slide@1.1.6, deep-equal@1.0.1, yamlish@0.0.7, nopt@3.0.4, mkdirp@0.5.1, difflet@0.2.6, glob@4.5.3, runforcover@0.0.2)
make: Entering directory `/opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
make: Leaving directory `/opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

make: Entering directory `/opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
make: Leaving directory `/opt/stocksearch/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can see the problem is with Fibers but no idea why it fails.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `nodeVersion: 0.10.40`

Comment: This actually worked and the app is now deployed! But why is that? Is it mup or meteor or the server that's incompatible with latest stable node?

Comment: @Arturs Demiters It's meteor itself. See this page https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-nodejs-0-12/2769